# Boolean Modifier results in artifacts

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface

I am decided to design a simple car wheel today. It is not meant to be realistic or anything like that; I am just making it for fun. At the center of the wheel, there are supposed to be 5 indentations for lug nuts. I am attempting to cut these in using the Boolean modifier. However, several artifacts appear when doing so. I uploaded a video to YouTube which shows these artifacts, and also **provides more information** about the whole situation. Please watch to the end.

https://youtu.be/lSZPen6HFE8

Thank you for any help you can provide.

EDIT: Here is a link to my .blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cocemui28Ql0XiKsitS77Nfk72j1CTLb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please share your file, I think you can't always get the exact result you want with booleans, you often need to rework the mesh after applying, like adding edge loops, it might be the case here

Comment: Here is a link to my mesh: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cocemui28Ql0XiKsitS77Nfk72j1CTLb/view?usp=sharing

Thank you so much for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have vertices overlaying, so use <kbd>W</kbd> > Remove Doubles, with a *Merge Distance* of 0.01. It will work, but the topology is not very good as you just have one face on the top. You should better create an inset with <kbd>i</kbd>, then boolean. The topology won't be perfect either as the amount of vertices of your small cylinder is not the same as your inset. Actually the simplest way to create your hole is to inset then extrude but you may want something non-destructive. In that case, maybe inset and use a cylinder with the same amount of vertices.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had tried insetting before but I didn't get the same results since I did not remove doubles with merge. I also used Auto Smooth, and shading artifacts disappeared!

Answer (score 1):

It can be several issues with Booleons, sometimes can be the underlying geometry you are cutting into, can you provide screen of the wireframe of the wheel, also can be worth turning on auto smooth. Will await screenshot of wire.

its fine for me with auto smooth ticked under object properties.

[image]

Comment: In the video I sent, you can see the wireframe of the wheel near the end. :)

Comment: Hey, I uploaded my .blend file as well if you'd be kind enough to look at it! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cocemui28Ql0XiKsitS77Nfk72j1CTLb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: updated answer with picture of auto smooth turned on using your blend file

Comment: Thanks! It worked!